# how form_key is forcefully required in the Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

form_key was always the required in the Magento, but in Magento 2.3 they made the form_key forcefully required. So, I want to know, how Magento is validating the form_key in every post request.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2  you can find a form key validator file from

```
vendor\magento\framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator.php
```

Take a look on the customer loginPost controller to see an example of how it's used

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a form key validation in place for all POST non-AJAX requests - if your **Action** doesn’t need that validation or you want to modify it you can implement **CsrfAwareActionInterface**.

URL : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/routing.html